# How to fit the size of a font to fit a PDF fillable box

Tags: pdf

More of a pdf editing question.

A lot of PDF forms restrict you to put 1 letter in each box when filling them
Something like this:
[image]

Has anyone found a way to fill these forms via computer ? Very hard to try to change the font size to fit these

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware of that, but apparently Adobe Acrobat reader (free) has this feature and it works amazingly well.

Open the document, then click "Fill and Sign" and hover over the boxed input element, it will fill it automatically within the borders